# Passing parameters conditionally to function

Tags: php, logic

I have an array:

```
    <pre>Array
(
    [fname] => adsff
    [lname] => adsf
    [address] => sdfaf
    [city] => sdaf
    [state] => dsfaf
    [zip] => adf
    [phone] => asdf
    [fax] => adsf
    [email] => asdff
    [salary] => asdaf
    [pemp] => asdfaf
    [noofyears] => asdfaf
    [married] => asdfaf
    [children] => asdfaf
    [refname1] => asdfaf
    [refphone1] => adsfaf
    [refname2] => asdfaf
    [refphone2] => sdfaf
    [refname3] => dfsg
    [refphone3] => sdf
    [bank] => sdf
)
```

I want to pass this array into mail such that if any of the field is blank the it then it is not used in mail
For example :
if only fname and lname has value in it , then the mail will be

```
First name = asdff
Last Name= adsf
```

Example 2: 
if only fname,lname and address has value in it , then the mail will be

```
 First name = asdff
    Last Name= adsf
Address=sdfaf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$mail = '';
foreach ($array as $name => $value) {
   if ($value) {
      $mail .= "$name = $value \n";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$array = array(); // your array that you posted...
$new_array = array();

foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
    if ( ! empty($val) ) $new_array[$key] = $val;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think use [**array_filter**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php),

**Example**:

```
<?php

$entry = array(
             0 => 'foo',
             1 => false,
             2 => -1,
             3 => null,
             4 => ''
          );

print_r(array_filter($entry));
?>

The above example will output:

Array
(
    [0] => foo
    [2] => -1
)
```

May this help you.